# copying two files using one command

Tags: command-line

**Copy two files** from the /etc directory.  They are **cust_orders** and **cust_names**.  Copy both files from the /etc directory to your home directory using ONE shell command with your home directory as the default directory that uses the **FEWEST keystrokes possible.**

Comment: @Kamran: What is the purpose of tagging `vi` in your question?

Comment: Another lab assignment / homework?

Answer (score 4):

I think the "best" single command would be

```
cp -i /etc/cust_{order,name}s $HOME
```

Answer (score 2):

> with your home directory as the default directory

So I'm assuming that means you are already in your home directory.  If not:

```
$ cd ~
```

To do this in the fewest keystrokes, I would try this:

```
$ cp /etc/cust_*s .
```

Or if you wanted to copy **only** those two files exactly, you could list them both in a text file:

```
/etc/cust_orders
/etc/cust_names
```

Save that as "f.txt" and then you could copy only those two files like this:

```
cp `cat f.txt` .
```

Comment: `cust_orders` and `cust_names` may not be the only folders beginning with *cust_* and ending with *s*, this will copy all of them, if not.

Comment: @Jobin Very true.  I was trying to find a happy medium of A) getting what he wanted and B) in the "FEWEST keystrokes possible."

Comment: The command should not introduce new problems(that of copying/moving others back) while solving old ones, @BryceAtNetwork23.

Comment: Well, if you want the fewest key strokes without  adding additional errors ... `cp -i /etc/cust_{order,name}s .` The -i option prevents you from inadvertently overwriting existing copies.